# can't call redux action from form submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When I try to submit the search form, it doesn't call the search action.
Is it because I'm passing the search function inefficiently as I'm passing it from one component to another? is there a way I could just use it directly from the import?

If I were to include the SearchBox component inside of Nav itself, it works.

If I added console.log(search) inside of handleSubmit, it outputs the function.

```
import { search } from './actions/userActions';

class Nav extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { search, self } = this.props;

        return (
            self === null 
            ? <NavLoggedOut search={search} />
            : <NavLoggedIn search={search}
        )
     }
}

const NavLoggedOut = (props) => {
    .....
}

const NavLoggedIn = (props) => {
    return (
        <header>
            <SearchBox search={search} />
        </header> 
    )
}

class SearchBox extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();  
        this.state = {
            name: ''
        }
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.id]: event.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.search(JSON.stringify({name: this.state.name}))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Search" />
                <button type="submit">search</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    self: state.store.self
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {search})(Nav);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these few lines

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

...

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return bindActionCreators({
       search
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Nav);
```

Now your `search` action should be available to the component `Nav` using `this.props.search()`

Remember to pass in parameters if it is expecting one (This depends on how you've written your `search` action)

Answer (score -1):

**Add this in your constructor**

```
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

and constructor should look like dis

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);  
        this.state = {
            name: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
```

Comment: doesn't change anything

Comment: pass props inside contructor and supe...i have edited my answer

Comment: that's what I have added. same thing

Comment: Assuming your class searchbox was in different file. As you mentioned from one component to another..
If you are using different files like navigation in one file and searchbox in one file then you need to import search action inside searchbox file instead of navigation and pass props inside constructor and super

Comment: as you are using mapdispatchtoprops in last line export default connect(mapStateToProps, {search})(Nav); ... u need to import action in this file.. and assuming you have imported connect from redux too..if not import connect too

Comment: .your code looks incomplete, as you are not showing statements like import connect from react-redux ...if still it doesn't work, please post complete code instead of parts and mentions if they are in diff files